# How can I replace an image with an SWF on click, and revert back to the image when another image is clicked and replaced with an SWF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

Let's say I have 3 images, each a placeholder for a Flash animation. When I click an image I want it to be replaced by its corresponding SWF. When I click another image I want the current SWF to be replaced by its placeholder image, and the newly clicked image to be replaced by its SWF.

I'm thinking of using the data attribute on the images to hold the path to the SWF…but this doesn't seem like the cleanest way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

IMAGE and SWF are quite different object. The first is a simple block element, the second is a more complex object/embed.

The simpliest way i see to achieve what you want is to load both image and swf, maybe in 2 different DIVs, and then swap them trough javascript, setting the "display" style as you wish.

Another way is create a DIV for each image and, always through javascript, dinamically rewrite the content on "click" event. Cleaner, but a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the html code using [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

BUT each time you will replace html to Flash, your animation will be restarted.

It means :

- Replace html->swf : Flash Player loads SWF
- Replace swf->html : Flash Player unloads SWF

I'm not talking about the SWF downloading (you can use cache for this) but only the SWF application loading.

Depending on your needs, this solution can fit but IMO you should think about not using Flash.

By the way, working with `display: none;` or `.hidden` (e.g.) will have the same effect as replacing html code.